# How do I add profile fields in specific section?

Tags: users

How do I add profile fields under the "Name" section of user profile page.
I was able to add fields at top of or at the bottom of user profile edit page, even found solution to edit contact section. But I am unable to find information on how I can add more fields to "Name" section.

[image]

When I'm using those actions:

```php
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
```

fields are getting added to the bottom.

Comment: This might not be possible in PHP

Comment: The User Profile page is rendered by wp-admin/user-edit.php. If you check the code in that file you would see that there are no hooks to add fields where you asked. The code can be seen here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/user-edit.php